# Partial Specialization of a variadic template function

Tags: c++, function, templates, variadic-templates, partial-specialization

I have this function which should work recursively.

```
template <class C, typename ...Arguments>
void addStyleClassRecursive(C *c, Arguments... arg)
{        
    c->addStyleClass(arg...);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<c->children().size(); ++i)
    {
        addStyleClassRecursive(c->children()[i], arg...);
    }       
}
```

Now it happens that at some point I hit a class (`Wt::WObject`) which has not the `addStyleClass` member function, so the compiler complains -rightly- about this problem.
Ok. So I thought to specialize the code, adding a version for `Wt::WObject`:

```
template <class C=Wt::WObject, typename ...Arguments>
void addStyleClassRecursive(Wt::WObject *c, Arguments... arg)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<c->children().size(); ++i)
    {
        addStyleClassRecursive(c->children()[i], arg...);
    }
}
```

This doesn't give a compiler error in itself, but it is utterly ignored (indeed the compiler keeps complaining about `WObject` not having the required member function, pointing to the same line within the general function).

So I tried to specialize it in this way

```
template <typename ...Arguments>
void addStyleClassRecursive<Wt::WObject, Arguments...>(Wt::WObject *c, Arguments... arg)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<c->children().size(); ++i)
    {
        addStyleClassRecursive(c->children()[i], arg...);
    }
}
```

Now the compiler complains about

```
non-type partial specialization 'addStyleClassRecursive<Wt::WObject, Arguments ...>' is not allowed
 void addStyleClassRecursive<Wt::WObject, Arguments...>(Wt::WObject *c, Arguments... arg);
                                                                                        ^
```

So can anyone point out how to attain the required result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
template <class C, typename ...Arguments>
auto addStyleClassRecursiveImpl(int, C *c, Arguments... arg)
-> decltype(c->addStyleClass(arg...), void()) {
    c->addStyleClass(arg...);
    // ... C has addStyleClass
}

template <class C, typename ...Arguments>
void addStyleClassRecursiveImpl(char, C *c, Arguments... arg) {
    // ... C has not addStyleClass
}

template <typename... T>
void addStyleClassRecursive(T ...&&t) {
    addStyleClassRecursiveImpl(0, std::forward<T>(t)...);
    // ...
}
```

The idea is to *tag-dispatch* the request to an internal implementation (called `addStyleClassRecursiveImpl` in the example) and use *sfinae* and function overloading to pick the right version up.

---

And of course, you cannot partially specialize a function template.

Comment: I had to make some little changes to make it work, but practically this was a plug-and-play solution. Thanks.

Comment: @DrHell I wrote it from a mobile phone, so please forgive me if there are some typos. I'm glad it works for you.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to sound arrogant or whatever, I explained that it needed some little changes just in case someone in the future wanted to use it and wondered why it didn't work at first run. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @DrHell You didn't sound arrogant!! Absolutely!! I only tried to explain why maybe I did some errors. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot partially specialize a function template.

What you can do is let the recursive template call a different function on its first variadic template arg, and then recursively call itself on the remainder of the arguments. Then you can fully specialize the helper function.